# association between two classes

Tags: javascript, reference, instance, es6-class

i want to call the virable and its value in class from other class
example :
if i create a class Doctor with one attribue the name of doctor(Name)

and i create another class of practice_doctor with one attribue too the name of practice doctor(p_name)

and in the class of practice doctor i create a void function that print the name of practice doctor and the name of the doctor that practice him in the class doctor.

in the main methond i create in instance of doctor class and assign him a name "jack"
and create in instance of practice doctor class and assign him an name such as a "mick"
so the function print info must print the name of the doctor and the name of practice doctor
such as "the doctor jack is practice doctor mick"

how can i association between too classes(doctor and practice doctor)?

Comment: Solution depends on your app architecture, you can declare one class instance as a property of another one, or you can create third class which will handle all doctor-practice_doctor pairs and so on.

Comment: I do not fully understand the concept. Does the OP in the end target a real practicing doctor which of cause is a doctor but has two names like the person is known as doctor jack but when practicing listens to mick?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @husseinK ... At SO it is considered to be a nice gesture from the one who got help, to provide some feedback and/or vote on answers and/or accept the answer which was the most helpful in solving the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

The next provided example code is a sophisticated guess about what the OP might want to achieve.

There is a base class `Doctor` and a sub class `PracticeDoctor` which extends the former base class. And the association the OP is talking about is not in between classes (at this level there is no other association than the inheritance chain of prototypes).

But the OP might have meant the association of two types (doctor instances). In this case a `PracticeDoctor` instance would aggregate another `Doctor` or `PracticeDoctor` instance/type as e.g. its own `associate` property.

```js
class Doctor {
  constructor(
    // assure default `name` value.
    name = 'unkown',
  ) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

class PracticeDoctor extends Doctor {
  constructor(
    // default value handling via super.    
    name,
    // assure default `associate` value.
    associate = new Doctor,
  ) {    
    // `name` initialization/assignement
    // via base class super call.
    super(name);
    
    // aggregation of another Doctor type.
    this.associate = associate;
  }
  teamedUpWith () {
    return [
      this.constructor.name,
      ' ',
      this.name,
      '\'s associate is ',
      this.associate.constructor.name,
      ' ',
      this.associate.name
    ].join('')
  } 
}

const drJack = new Doctor('Jack');
const drJill = new PracticeDoctor('Jill');
const drMick = new PracticeDoctor('Mick', drJack);
const drJess = new PracticeDoctor('Jess', drJill);

console.log({ drJack, drJill, drMick, drJess });
console.log(
  'drJack?.teamedUpWith?.() ...',
  drJack?.teamedUpWith?.()
);
console.log(
  'drJill.teamedUpWith() ...',
  drJill.teamedUpWith()
);
console.log(
  'drMick.teamedUpWith() ...',
  drMick.teamedUpWith()
);
console.log(
  'drJess.teamedUpWith() ...',
  drJess.teamedUpWith()
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @husseinK ... From the above provided approach/solution are there any questions left?